# How to trigger Azure Logic App when dropping file in Sharepoint folder

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-logic-apps

I created a Logic App that uses the Sharepoint trigger "When a file is created or modified in a folder". It works perfectly when I upload a file in Sharepoint online (in a Sharepoint browser tab). But, it doesn't work when I drop a file in my synced Windows explorer folder.

I read that someone faced the same problem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/41215/logic-app-why-does-sharepoint-file-properties-trig.html. Here it says:

> Move files and flow runs When you move one or more files from one
> document library to another, the original file is moved from the
> source library to the destination library. Moving the file does not
> alter any custom metadata, including when the file was created and
> modified. Hence, this action does not trigger any flows for those file
> updates associated in the library where it was moved.
>
> Syncing files to your OneDrive for business and SharePoint document
> libraries When users sync one or more files from one document library
> to another, the original file is moved (synced) from your client to
> the destination library. Syncing the file will not alter any custom
> metadata including when the file was created and modified. Hence, this
> action will not trigger any flows for those file syncs in that library
> or in your OneDrive for business.

The thing is that I NEED this Logic App to run by just dropping this file in a Windows Explorer folder (which is a Sharepoint folder shared with a certain person). Do you know how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It started working for me when I used the OneDrive - `When a file is created` Connector because we use OneDrive for Windows Explorer and need to include the folder where the trigger should be invoked. We must set `Include subfolder` to true if we want the trigger to be fired while adding any file to the subfolders.

Here are the screenshots of the logic app working
[image]

**When adding file in subfolders**
[image]

**When adding file in root folder**
[image]